# Is mutual information transitive?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Suppose A, B and C are random variables. Given that the mutual information between A and B is very large and also the mutual information between B and C is very large, could we conclude that the mutual information between A and C is also large? In other words, if we know the mutual information between A and B and the mutual information between B and C, what could we say about the mutual information between A and C?

Thanks,

Comment: Imagine H(B|A)=H(C|B)=0, i.e. maximum mutual information between A and B, and between C and B. Now I claim the mutual information between A and C is low. To refute this claim, I could say given A, I know B because H(B|A)=0. Similarly, given B, I know C because H(C|B)=0. So by knowing A, I could find B and subsequently I could find C. This implies a large mutual information between A and C. This was an intuitive proof. I cannot prove it mathematically.

Comment: I see. Then the last sentence of your post is misleading.

Comment: Thanks Did. In my comment, I assume maximum mutual information. If the mutual information between A and B and between B and C is not large, then I cannot prove the transitivity even intuitively. That is why I preferred to ask a more general question and add the last sentence.

Comment: Intuitively, when viewing it as the "intersection" of sets; you will only get lower bounds, say something like $$I(A;C) \geq I(A;B) + I(B;C) - 1$$
With $I(A;B), I(B;C) \geq c$ you can only reach $I(A;C) \geq 2c - 1 < c$ for $c < 1$

Comment: Arguing based on set theoretic intuition is not always true. Just consider the relation between $I(A;B)$ and $I(A;B|C)$. There is no definite relation between them unlike what set theoretical intuition might suggest.

Comment: @AlexR It is not mathematically provable, isn't it? and what is that (-1)?

Comment: That $-1$ is what you can lose (in set theoretical things, i.e. if $I(A;B)$ is identified with $A\cap B$)
Say $A = \{0,1\}, B=\{1,2\}, C=\{2,3\}$, $|A\cap B| = |B\cap C| = 1$ but $$|A \cap C| = 0 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - 1 = \frac{|A\cap B|}{|B|} + \frac{|B\cap C|}{|B|} - 1$$
But that's just my idea of this - I'm no specialist in this region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation between $I(A;C)$ and $I(A;B)$,$I(B;C)$ depends on the joint probability distribution of $A,B,C$. For instance if you have the Markov relation that $P(A|BC)=P(A|B)$, then this will imply that:
$$
I(A;B)=I(A;BC)\geq I(A;C).
$$
Similarly
$$
I(B;C)=I(BA;C)\geq I(A;C).
$$
Therefore 
$$
\min\left(I(A;B),I(B;C)\right)\geq I(A;C).
$$
On the other hand if you assume different Markov relation as $P(A|BC)=P(A|C)$, you get:
$$
I(A;C)=I(A;BC)\geq I(A;B).
$$
So there is no specific relation between mutual informations if you do not know their joint distribution.

Comment: I see. So even knowing that for example H(B|A)=H(C|B)=0 does not help?

Comment: This is different. $H(B|A)=0$ means $B=f(A)$ and similarly $C=g(B)=g(f(A))$ so $H(C|A)=0$ too.

Comment: Based on what you said, if H(B|A)<c and H(C|B)<c, I cannot make any conclusion on H(C|A), right?

Comment: The conditional entropy is different from mutual information. For conditional entropy you can have: $H(C|A)\leq H(BC|A)=H(B|A)+H(C|BA)\leq H(B|A)+H(C|B)\leq 2c$. But saying that mutual information is very large does not say very much about the conditional entropy.

Comment: If I(A;B)=H(B)-H(B|A) is very large, we can say H(B|A) is close to 0. So I think knowing the mutual information is very large or very small, we can infer something about the conditional entropy as well.

Comment: You have to first clarify what do you mean by $I(A;B)$ large. Because if $a-b$ is large, this does not mean that $b$ is very small. It depends how large $a$ is. On the other hand you can write $I(A;B)=H(A)-H(A|B)$ as well. If your argument is correct then $H(A|B)$ should be small too. So why saying   $H(B|A)$ is small and not  $H(A|B)$ ?

Comment: $I(A;B)=H(B)-H(B|A)$, it means $0 \leq I(A;B) \leq H(B)$. So the largest value of $I(A;B)$ is $H(B)$ and it happens when $H(B|A)=0$. When I say $I(A;B)$ is large, it implies that $H(B|A)$ should be close to 0. I think we could say if $I(A;B)$ is large, then both $H(A|B)$ and $H(B|A)$ must be small.

Comment: Dear Seyed, when you talk about the maximum of a function, you should first determine the search space. When you talk about $\max_{P(A|B)}I(A;B)$, then the answer is $H(B)$. But when you talk about  $\max_{P(B|A)}I(A;B)$ the answer is $H(A)$. And even more when you are talking about $\max_{P(A,B)}I(A;B)$ the answer is $\max(\log|A|,\log|B|)$. One should be very careful when he talks about maximum, minimum, large or small. When you say something is large you have to first clarify what do you mean by "Large" mathematically.

Comment: On the other hand, if $H(A|B)$ and $H(B|A)$ are both very small then you have $H(A)$ is very close to $H(B)$.

Comment: Thanks very much dear Arash. Your comments were very helpful. It was important to me to know that $H(C|A) \leq 2c$ where $H(B|A) \leq c$ and $H(C|B) \leq c$.